# I am trying to combine multiple rows into single rows in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three groups of rows right now and I am trying to combine those groups of rows into single rows. [Current State of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThDx7.png) (Image only shows two genes, but I promise there's a third)

I have three separate genes, each having 61 NX values associated with them. I am trying to combine the 61 rows for each gene into a single row for each gene with all of its NX values listed across the row so that I can easily find the mean. I have no idea how to go about this. Please help.

Here is my code thus far if it matters.

```
 import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rna_consensus.tsv', delimiter='\t')

df = df[df['Gene name'].isin(["ENPP4", "RAD52", "ICA1"])]

df = df[['Gene name', 'NX']]
```

Comment: Why not just directly find the mean of NX of each gene ?

Comment: Mostly because I'm very new to this and didn't realize it was an option.

Comment: Please provide example data in text site-side

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) to directly get the mean of `NX` grouped unde `Gene name`, as follows:

```
df.groupby('Gene name', as_index=False)['NX'].mean()
```